# Change colors in SVG graph generated from Google's API

Tags: css, svg, graph, google-api

I have this small graph I created using Google JS Api and a tutorial found online and I would like to change few things in the generated SVG.

What I would like to achieve is: change graph's colors, hide / delete the legend on top right.

This is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<style>
    body
{
margin: 100px;
}
.form-control
{
display: block;
width: 200px;
}

svg g:nth-child(4) {
border: 1px solid yellow !important;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="getInfoMath" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="getInfoRus"  />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="getInfoEco"  />
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="getInfoMom"  />
<input id="Start" type="button" value="Create Pie Chart" class="btn btn-danger" />
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
<script>

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Callback that creates and populates a data table,
// instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
// draws it.

  
function drawChart() {
document.getElementById('Start').onclick = function () {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var math = document.getElementById('getInfoMath').value;
var rus = document.getElementById('getInfoRus').value;
var eco = document.getElementById('getInfoEco').value;
var mom = document.getElementById('getInfoMom').value
if (math <= 0 || rus <= 0 || eco <= 0 ) {alert('Error'); return;}
data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
data.addRows([
['Ble', Number(math)],
['Bla', Number(rus)],
['Blo', Number(eco)],
['Bli', Number(mom)]
]);

// Set chart options
var options = {'title':'Something here as a test',
               'width':600,
               'height':800};

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}

// Create the data table.

}


</script>

</html>
```

To change the colors I tried this in CSS but it did not worked

```
svg g:nth-child(4) {
fill: #000000 !important;
}
```

Here a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gu4czkb8/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding a Legend, don't create it.

In modern Browsers you can create your own Web Component `<pie-chart>`

Built your own from: https://pie-meister.github.io/

```html
<script src="https://pie-meister.github.io/PieMeister.min.js">999 bytes</script>

<pie-chart pull="100" pulltext="100" style="width:180px">
  <style>
    text {
      font: 6em Arial;
      text-anchor: middle;
      fill: white;
    }
  </style>
  <slice size="10%"></slice>
  <slice size="20%" pull></slice>
  <slice size="30%"></slice>
  <slice size></slice>
</pie-chart>
```